# GitLab Container Registry: errors: denied: requested access to the resource is denied [...] error parsing HTTP 401 response body

Tags: docker, gitlab, podman

When I run `podman push` (the equiv of `docker push`) to get my image up to GitLab's container registry, I'm getting the following error.

> errors: denied: requested access to the resource is denied [...] error parsing HTTP 401 response body: unexpected end of JSON input: ""

You can see it all here,

```
❯ podman push localhost/acme-web-release registry.gitlab.com/evancarroll/acme-backend
Getting image source signatures
Error: trying to reuse blob sha256:1e05dc5a6784f6e7375fe1f73dc2b02f7d184bc53a0150daf06062dcbfde02d4 at destination: checking whether a blob sha256:1e05dc5a6784f6e7375fe1f73dc2b02f7d184bc53a0150daf06062dcbfde02d4 exists in registry.gitlab.com/evancarroll/acme-backend: errors:
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
error parsing HTTP 401 response body: unexpected end of JSON input: ""
```

I've confirmed that I've `podman login` (the podman analog of `docker login`) with a Personal Access Token that grants `write_registry`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A personal access token to push to the registry does not *just* require `write_registry` but **ALSO** `read_registry` or `read_api` (more general).

Answer (score 0):

firstly, you can just make `docker logout registry.gitlab.com`, and login again `docker login registry.gitlab.com`, it's wrong because old token have not access for new registry